# How can I insert records 'into null' in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, insert, null

I'm looking for a way to insert records into a 'black hole'; i.e. execute a query for a certain table successfully, but make the records disappear. Something like `INSERT INTO NULL`, if you will. MySQL has the [BLACKHOLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html) engine, can Oracle do something similar?

The only thing I could come up with was:

- creating a view with `SELECT NULL FROM DUAL`
- creating a trigger with `INSTEAD OF INSERT` and `BEGIN NULL; END;`

Is this okay?

Obviously, the optimal way is not to execute the insert statement, but I have no control over this - I have to fix this in the DB.

What's the best way to handle this? (the solution with the least impact on performance)

Comment: The instead of trigger is the way to go. Don't try and insert into dual. It breaks things terribly on some versions of Oracle

Comment: If you do this for testing purposes, you could also wrap the inserts into a transaction, then rollback at the end. I think it's still faster than the trigger.

Comment: I too think the view is the way to go. But I'd also be reluctant to base that view on the `dual` table. Just create a dummy table instead.

Comment: Maybe a temporary table on Oracle (which works much differently than on eg SQL Server) would work for you? The performance of this is likely to be *much* better than the trigger solution which will have a lot of row-by-row overhead. If you need to discard millions of rows, the temporary table approach will be *much* faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could do something like this on Oracle is to use a `temporary table` with `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS`. The rows will "disappear" at the end of the transaction. If you're using a host environment such as JDBC with autocommit, this will make it look like what you describe. If performance is important, this approach will be *much* faster than the "discarding trigger" approach.

Syntax:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_table (
  column1 INTEGER,
  column2 VARCHAR2(100),
  ...
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN11633

Comment: Unfortunately, the table needs to be persistent...

Comment: Oracle temporary tables *are* persistent! It's just the contents that are temporary.

Comment: If the structures are persistent, this is most definitely a very elegant solution :) What happens if you don't commit?

Comment: The records will remain visible until `commit` or `rollback` -- but only to your session, not to any others. Records in temporary tables are *never* visible to other sessions -- even with `on commit preserve rows` (then the rows "disappear" on logout).

Like I said, this may or may not work for you, but would be the way I would try to solve the problem, if possible.

NB records are stored (ie: temporarily) in the default temporary tablespace of the user, or you can explicitly assign a tablespace at table creation time.